# Unable to mount Windows partition - Not hibernated or Fast restarted

Tags: dual-boot, mount, windows-8

I having some trouble installing Ubuntu on my computer. I think the issue is with my Windows partition not being mounted correctly.

I am currently "trying" Ubuntu using LiveUSB. I am able to mount every single partition except for my Windows 8 partition. When I try to mount it, it says

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb5 at /media/ubuntu/OS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb5" "/media/ubuntu/OS"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Now, I am quite sure I shut down my Windows partition before starting LiveUSB. I also disabled Fast Restart on my Windows OS. What is going wrong here?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong in your senario as I don't have windows 8, but you can check out this: http://askubuntu.com/a/145904/115738, and also I think that you want to disable hybrid sleep? I am not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Boot windows and properly shutdown.